# How to remove substring from path including " ' " with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have this string:

```
var path = "/All Files/Personal Files/admin's Files/";
```

I want to remove the "admin's Files/" string, but it will not work with replace because of the " ' " in admin's word.

```
path = path .replace("admin's Files/", "");   // will return - undefined is not a function
```

What to do?

Comment: Have you tried escaping the "'"?  path = path .replace("admin\'s/", "");

Comment: @Dani this isn't an escaping issue... You don't need to escape single-quotes in double-quoted delimited strings.

Comment: yes, getting the same error

Comment: @AngularOne  Can you post a fiddle with your example?

Comment: You are looking in the wrong place – the code as shown works fine, see http://jsfiddle.net/vxH4G/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to do this in firebug javascript console:

```
var path = "/All Files/Personal Files/admin's Files/";
console.log(typeof path)    //logs "string"
console.log(path) //logs "/All Files/Personal Files/admin's Files/"
path = path .replace("admin's Files/", "");
console.log(path) //logs "/All Files/Personal Files/"
```

And it works, check if your `path` variable is a string.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to replace `admin's/` but that substring doesn't appear in `path`. Update the code as follows:

```
var path = "/All Files/Personal Files/admin's Files/";

path = path.replace("admin's Files/", '');
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/p67ss/)

Comment: The space doesn't matter. Your code will still work with the space http://jsfiddle.net/p67ss/1/

Comment: What if the string to replace is inside a var? 
`code` var x = "admin's Files/";
path = path.replace(x, ""); `code`

Comment: your code works great, don't know what I'm doing wrong to get this error - TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: You must have an error on another line. Please share you whole code.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying, There is nowhere a string as `"admin's/"` in your path variable. That's why it's not replacing.

You can replace either `"admin's"` or `"admin's Files/"`.

You should try

```
path = path.replace("admin's Files/", "");
```

Comment: Please upvote answers already posted, rather than duplicating them.